# MYSQL getting the difference of two results

Tags: mysql, intersect

ok so my problem is that I have a set of results:

```
ID  CODE
1   A
1   B
3   C
```

I also have another table of:

```
CODE
A
B
C
```

What I want to get using SQL is a query of CODES that each result from table 1 is missing. So basically:

```
ID  CODE
1   C
3   A
3   B
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I Don't understand your question. Doesn't your first table already have a 'code' for each 'id'? Maybe what you are looking for is PHP - Array_diff - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT     a.id, b.code
FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM idcodes) a
CROSS JOIN codes b
LEFT JOIN  idcodes c ON a.id = c.id AND b.code = c.code
WHERE      c.id IS NULL
ORDER BY   a.id, b.code
```

If you have another table that stores unique entries for `id`, it would be better to just use that table instead rather than a `DISTINCT` subselect:

```
SELECT     a.id, b.code
FROM       ids a
CROSS JOIN codes b
LEFT JOIN  idcodes c ON a.id = c.id AND b.code = c.code
WHERE      c.id IS NULL
ORDER BY   a.id, b.code
```

---

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa8c3/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`. Construct the full list of possible variations with a Cartesian join and then ensure what you have isn't in this list.

```
select id, code
  from idcode_table x
 where not exists ( select 1 
                      from idcode_table a
                     cross join code_table b
                     where b.code = x.code
                       and a.id = x.id )
```

This can also be re-written with a `not in`.

```
select id, code
  from idcode_table
 where (id, code) not in ( select distinct a.id, b.code
                             from idcode_table a
                            cross join code_table b )
```

The `distinct` is optional. It will make it slower to construct the list of possibles but quicker to determine if you have one of them already. I'd test it to see which is quicker.